# Changing a form field's 'required' property with save_model in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have tried all the different examples and methods I could find on Stack Overflow for this, and for whatever reason, can't get this to work properly.

So in my admin.py I have a UserForm and and UserAdmin. Based on the condition where a boolean is checked within the form, I want to change the 'required' attribute on a few different form fields to 'false' so I can effectively save. I've used a few different print statements to ascertain that the 'required' is in fact getting changed to false when the condition is met, however, when I try and save, it won't let me as the fields highlight and say they're still required.

It is almost like the save_model doesn't care how I edit the form, that the old form and its 'required' attributes are overriding my changes. Thanks for any help!

**admin.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = forms.CharField(min_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'CA'}))
    zipcode = forms.CharField(max_length=5, min_length=5,)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Order
    form = UserForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.pickup_only == 1:
            form.fields['address'].required = False
            form.fields['city'].required = False
            form.fields['state'].required = False
            form.fields['zipcode'].required = False
        return super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

---

revised code for UserForm:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    address = cleaned_data.get('address')
    state = cleaned_data.get('state')
    city = cleaned_data.get('city')
    zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
    pickup_only = cleaned_data.get('pickup_only')

    if pickup_only == True:
        # I STUCK IN ADDRESS TO EMPHASIZE THE ERROR IN SCREENSHOT
        self.fields_required(['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'phone', 'email', 'address'])
    else:
        self.cleaned_data['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip code'] = ''
    return self.cleaned_data

def fields_required(self, fields):
    for field in fields:
        print(field)
        # RETURNS: first_name, last_name, dob, phone, email, address
        if not self.cleaned_data.get(field, ''):
            msg = forms.ValidationError("This field is required. Custom.")
            self.add_error(field, msg)
```

When I save I get this:

[image]

Comment: can you add `UserForm`?

Comment: Yes sir, will do..

Comment: Apart from that, in your `UserAdmin` class you'd defined `model = Order` and in your `UserForm` its `model = User`. Will that is a problem?

Comment: I have model = order in my UserAdmin as it's referencing the model class that I have for an inline display. As that's not an argument being passed in the save_model function, I figured it wouldn't be relevant. At any rate, I commented it out to see if would have any bearing on the code not working, and it unfortunately did not.

Comment: What I think would be better is, define those fields in model as `blank=True` and handle the ***validation manually in `clean()` method of form***

Comment: How would that work in determining upon save of the form whether or not the boolean checkbox was checked or not? Can you give an example please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to tweak it a little bit to fit your needs, but you could try something like this in your clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    state = cleaned_data.get('state')
    zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
    pickup_only = cleaned_data.get('pickup_only')

    if pickup_only == True:
        self.fields_required(['any_fields_required',])
    else:
        self.cleaned_data['state', 'zip code'] = ''
    return self.cleaned_data

def fields_required(self, fields):
    for field in fields:
        if not self.cleaned_data.get(field, ''):
            msg = forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
            self.add_error(field, msg)
```

Also, as one of the commenters mentioned, you should not specify your model=Order in the UserAdmin. Your UserAdmin is for the User model. That isn't the proper way to add inlines. See below:

```
# You can also use (admin.TabularInline) depending on your needs.
class OrderInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Order
    list_display = ('order_fields',)
    fieldsets = (
        ((''), {'fields': ('order_fields',)}),
    )

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    inlines = [OrderInline,]
```

Add an init method to your form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = forms.CharField(min_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'CA'}))
    zipcode = forms.CharField(max_length=5, min_length=5,)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['address'].required = False
        self.fields['city'].required = False
        self.fields['state'].required = False
        self.fields['zipcode'].required = False

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        address = cleaned_data.get('address')
        state = cleaned_data.get('state')
        city = cleaned_data.get('city')
        zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
        pickup_only = cleaned_data.get('pickup_only')

        if pickup_only == True:
            self.fields_required(['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'phone', 'email', 'address'])
        else:
            self.cleaned_data['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip code'] = ''
        return self.cleaned_data

    def fields_required(self, fields):
        for field in fields:
            if not self.cleaned_data.get(field, ''):
                msg = forms.ValidationError("This field is required. Custom.")
                self.add_error(field, msg)
```

Try this. If it works then I don't think you have to override the save method in your UserAdmin. I would avoid that anyway unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried the above code to fit the fields I needed for it and it didn't seem to work. It doesn't seem the fields_required method is being called correctly. I tried printing from within the method to debug, but couldn't get any output when I tried saving. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Dev - what error are you getting if any? What is going on in the form? Is the model saving?

Comment: I'm not getting back any error, however, I've been messing around with the code to better understand what's going on. So far I have: if pickup_only is true, self.fields_required(['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'phone', 'email',])  --> these are the fields I want required. Then for the ELSE, I have the address fields (city, state, zip). For the fields_required method, when I print the fields it prints everything but the address fields. I tried adding 'address' to self.fields_required array and the error message spit out, but I'm obviously doing something wrong or have things mixed up.

Comment: Is there some way I can better explain this by editing your answer the way you have it and then add comments directly to the line by line code?

Comment: @Dev - can you please put your new code in your original question so I can better visualize it. What is happening to the form in the view when you submit it? Is it still requesting that you fill out the fields?

Comment: Also, I think the model = Order was a typo when I was trying to debug something at some point. I have my inlines = [OrderInline] already and a separate TabularInline class. Can't remember why that is still there. I'll remove it in any case.

Comment: It's funny you mention the __init__ method! That was LITERALLY the first thing I tried before the save_model override, as I didn't want to resort to that either. Good call. I had the same lines verbatim that you used, and even tried it with the clean and fields_required override method you shared. The only problem is that it initializes with the address fields required as false, so when I save without the pickup_only boolean checked (as true) it will still save. I'd like those fields to be required only if true, if that's possible. Appreciate all your help btw! :)

Comment: @Dev - yes the init method in conjunction with the fields_required method and the if else statement should get you what you want, but check and see.

Comment: I mean I already tried it, and it still saved when left unchecked :(

Comment: @Dev - try just if pickup_only:

Comment: @Dev - ah I think I know the problem. It was my mistake. See the answer again for the change. Move the fields_required method outside the clean method.

Comment: That worked when I set pickup_only == False. I had a feeling I needed to reverse the logic, but it works! Thanks for you help brotha! There was one thing left in your edit, and that was the fields_required method was indented under the clean method. I can edit that for you if you want. Let me know! Grateful for your help, you saved me a lot of frustration <3